# Using an expression for ngclass with multiple classes

Tags: angularjs

This is how you add multiple classes using ng-class:

```
<div ng-class="{a: first, b: second, c: third}"></div>
```

How can I make the class-name itself (i.e. `a` or `b`, or `c`) the result of an expression, whilst having multiple classes? I want one of the class names to be the value of a property on the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best solution is to change the `ngClass` content with a function, such as:

```
<div ng-class="myFunction()">hola</div>
```

Then define a function that do what it is originally specified in the `ngClass` attribute:

```
$scope.myFunction = function () {
    var x = {};
    x['a'] =  $scope.first;
    x['b'] = $scope.second;
    x[$scope.myClass] = $scope.third;
    return x;
};
```

In this way, the third class is relative to a variable (the other three variables are for reference to first, second and third).

If you you check this jsfiddle, and you press "add C" and then "switch C with D" how the class are swapped:

http://jsfiddle.net/mhonns9d/

Comment: Where `$scope.first` etc are expressions evaluating to truthy or falsey to indicate presence of the class?

Comment: Yes, in the same way as it's inline